# Python Get Docstring Without Going into Interactive Mode

Tags: python, interactive

I want to grab the docstring in my commandline application, but every time I call the builtin help() function, Python goes into interactive mode.

How do I get the docstring of an object and **not** have Python grab focus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any docstring is available through the `.__doc__` property:

```
>>> print str.__doc__
```

In python 3, you'll need parenthesis for printing:

```
>>> print(str.__doc__)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dir(`{insert class name here}`)` to get the contents of a class and then iterate over it, looking for methods or other stuff. This example looks in a class `Task`for methods starting with the name `cmd` and gets their docstring:

```
command_help = dict()

for key in dir( Task ):
    if key.startswith( 'cmd' ):
        command_help[ key ] = getattr( Task, key ).__doc__
```

Answer (score 1):

`.__doc__` is the best choice. However, You can also use `inspect.getdoc` to get `docstring`. One advantage of using this is, it removes indentation from docstrings that are indented to line up with blocks of code.

**Example:**

```
In [21]: def foo():
   ....:     """
   ....:     This is the most useful docstring.
   ....:     """
   ....:     pass
   ....: 

In [22]: from inspect import getdoc

In [23]: print(getdoc(foo))
This is the most useful docstring.

In [24]: print(getdoc(str))
str(object='') -> string

Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
```